# Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Как пишется слово «автомоечный»?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

***Авто...*** — первая часть сложных слов, пишется слитно.

Яндекс.Словари › Орфографический словарь. — 2004